# MVC home route to be default always as /shopping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Am trying to default my route on home page and make it show on Google.

My site is *`www.timefor.com`* but I always want it to show *`www.timefor.com/shopping`*

the default controller is home/index as normal. but the website shows as "www.timefor.com" when i run it

How do I get shopping being defaulted.

I have tried changing the default route map but no luck.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MyNamespace.Controllers" }
);
```

*HomeController*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

When I start the project I want the URL to be as:

`www.timefor.com/shopping`

Comment: You need to redirect people from the home page to the shopping page. However, I would strongly discourage this, making people navigate away from your home page is not a great experience.

Comment: "i have tried changing the default route map but no luck." but the code you posted is the default route, I don't see any change besides the `namespaces` assignment

Comment: no the home page i want it to have that url, my site is www.timefor.com    but whenever i have someone coming to my site i want it shown as www.timefor.com/shopping

Comment: @DavidG I believe they are trying to set the default route, not perform a redirection

Comment: @ma32112345 is shopping a controller action or are you trying to have the index displayed under that url?

Comment: yes, i also want it showing up in google as well. rather than being www.timefor.com i want google to show it as www.timefor.com/shopping

Comment: What you are saying isn't clear. Do you want the HTML that is displayed on `www.timefor.com` to show the `/shopping` page? You don't want the URL to also show `/shopping`?

Comment: @Nkosi shopping is just the index to be displayed. the controller is home/index as normal, but when i load page locally it comes as "www.timefor.com/" but i always want it to come as "www.timefor.com/shopping"

Comment: @DavidG sorry dave i mean i want the url to show as www.timefor.com/shopping as the main page

Comment: You can only do that by redirecting users to /shopping (or use the javascript history api to push /shopping up to the URL without a redirect, but that will not be reflected in Google search results).

Comment: OK, then my first comment still stands. And also, my name is David, not Dave thanks.

Comment: @ma32112345 then what David said is acurate, you would need to redirect or rewrite the URL

Comment: @DavidG Sorry David.but there is no shopping page. its just a url i want

Comment: Then that makes even less sense. And I even more strongly discourage you to do this.

Comment: the reason for that is so people when they see the site or are on the page they know its about shopping. also i want it to show on google that the link is "www.timefor.com/shopping" and not "www.timefor.com" i think for seo its better for it to have /shopping as that is what people search  @DavidG

Comment: Do you want the entire application to run under Shopping? Or just the Home controller?

Comment: Change the name of the current HomeController to ShoppingController, then /shopping will work (as long as you have an Index() action result within it), then create a new HomeController and in the index() action in the new HomeController, redirect the users to /Shopping

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto just the home controller

Comment: People should know it's about shopping from the content of the page, not from the URL. Most people will never even look at the URL.

Comment: This makes me think the OP just wanted the domain `timeforshopping.com` and is looking for a workaround

Comment: @HaukurHaf i have updated how my controller looks. but when i run this it doesnt come as/home so that is not the fix

Comment: @ma32112345 You have to *redirect*, not return a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible using **http redirection**.

**1. Let's start by getting /shopping to work:**

Rename your current `HomeController` to `ShoppingController`.

Run the project and append /shopping to the url - it should show your frontpage.

**2. Perform the redirection**

Create a new `HomeController`. Then change it so it looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("/shopping");
    }
}
```

Now, whenever users visit your site, they are redirected to /shopping

By using a permanent redirect, search engines like Google, should index your page using the /shopping URL.

Comment: i dont have a shoppingcontroller as its not needed. when i use redirectpermanent its error showing as 404 - The resource cannot be found.

Comment: You *need* a shopping controller if you want /shopping to work.  It's as simple as that.  Just follow the steps outlined in my answer and you'll get the functionality you want.

Comment: RedirectPermanent opens it as /shopping but the page doesnt show it says Hmmm... cannot reach this page

Comment: Have you renamed your HomeController to ShoppingController?